# Quick way to open a distant file in vim in command line

Tags: vim

Suppose I have two files with the following filepaths:

```
~/another/project/file1.txt
~/this/is/some/very/deep/project/file2.txt
```

As you could see, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are located "far way" from each other in the filesystem.

Now suppose I'm editing `file1.txt`, and I want to open up `file2.txt` in a `vsplit` window. The fastest method I'd chose to open up `file2.txt` is

```
:vsplit ~/this/is/some/very/deep/project/file2.txt
```

which is obviously not efficient, even with fuzzy completion.

Is there a way to quickly "bookmark" or "jump to a directory" to reach `file2.txt` quickly?

My initial thoughts would be to execute a command from the shell (within command mode, using `!`) to somehow facilitate the jumping. Using something like [jump](https://github.com/flavio/jump) might help, but I wouldn't know how.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a global mark, as described in the answer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581505/vim-create-marks-across-files

If you make a mark with a capital letter like `mA`, you can return to that file by going to that mark with `'A`.

This'll work across sessions if your `.viminfo` is saving things properly.

Comment: You learn a new vim trick everyday. This seems more preferable than symlinking files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same files regularly you can use a symbolic link.

Make a folder to keep your links in.

```
mkdir ~/links/
```

link your files.

```
ln ~/another/project/file1.txt ~/links/file1.txt
ln ~/this/is/some/very/deep/project/file2.txt ~/links/file2.txt
```

You can also name your link differently. If your file is somereallylongname.txt you can link it to shname.txt

```
ln ~/this/is/some/very/deep/project/somereallylongname.txt ~/links/shname.txt
```

Comment: I suppose a symbolic link would be a solution. But like you mentioned, I'd make a link if I used the same files regularly; for my use case, I'm hoping to only open up `file2.txt` once or twice.

Comment: Fair enough. Do these files usually exist in the same deep directory. you could link the whole directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer presented to me by a friend was to use the [ctrlp](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) plugin. The ctrlp plugin makes it easy to search for a file though multiple directories at the same time.

EDIT: The default settings for ctrlp would actually start searching from the root of the project; technically, one would have to set the root node differently to get it to work properly.